# Drools KieScanner -- is it possible to load settings.xml from within the executable?

Tags: java, maven, drools, kie

I'm using `KieScanner` with Drools 7.x in a Spring Boot project, and dynamic rule loading is working just fine locally.

However, I've run into a problem when preparing to deploy to an environment.

Drools uses an embedded Maven client to check against a remote repository or new versions of rules artifacts. Locations of remote repositories are through the standard Maven `settings.xml`. The [Drools documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.22.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_settings_xml_and_remote_repository_setup) specifies that the location of `settings.xml` can be:

- The Maven install: `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`
- A user’s install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`
- Folder location specified by the system property `kie.maven.settings.custom`

I looked into the approach they seem to require, but because of infrastructure configuration restrictions in the organization, I'm unable to deploy a static file to the hosts running our executable (and Docker is also not an option).

Is there any way to either bundle the `settings.xml` in the executable and load it from there, or to provide settings for the remote repository in another fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually dug into the source for the `KieScanner` and found that there's a feature in the library which it uses for resolving the path to `settings.xml` which is documented in the source project, but not in the Drools documentation. That library takes a `String` as a path, but if the path does not exist, it attempts to transform it to a URL. I was then able to host the `settings.xml` remotely and refer to it by URL.